# Why doesn't my App Script update current data?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have built a spreadsheet that pulls NBA player props from Draftkings Sportsbook. The script worked fine the first time I ran it and pulled the appropriate data. However, when I went in today to re-run the script and pull the updated prop lines the data in each tab did not change. The only work around I could figure out was to copy each script file, run the script, and then delete the duplicate script file. I assume there has to be a better/different way of doing this. I attached a link to the googlesheet that also has access to the app script. Any guidance would be appreciated!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ErKFLFetC8ab0JAX9K92VpwuJGvyAZHp-TUyM4BH_f4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Never use same function names across different scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

- Your functions within the scripts have the same names.

#### Solution:

- Rename the functions. All functions inside all the scripts should be unique.

[image: steals]

[image: turnovers]

Upon testing after the modifications, it did update current data on the respective sheet.

#### Note:

- The reason why your workaround works is that the function that belongs to the last script will be the one that is executed.

#### Test:

[image: proof1]

[image: proof2]

#### Output:

[image: output]

Thus continuously duplicating the script to the bottom with the same function name will be the one to be executed.

Comment: can you help me understand why the script isn't working for the double double odds? Here is the place that I am trying to get the information from:

https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/leagues/basketball/88670846?category=player-props&subcategory=double-double

When I change the value in the source, as I did for the others, it gives me an error. Again, here is the googlesheet with the script! I need help with the file named Double Double.

Comment: Hi @PerriElizabeth, Let's post it as another question since the original issue here is already solved. Let's try to have a post specific and avoid piling up questions.

Comment: @PerriElizabeth, I have posted an answer on your recent post. Check it if it works on you.